# Is it ever useful to indicate an edit in my post?

Tags: discussion, edits

Very often you will find a section which looks like the following in a post:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>
> **Edit:**
>
> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

<sub>Find an example of such an edit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49855634/revisions) (edit #2).</sub>

I have mainly found two areas where this is used:

1. To provide a better answer/question, basically rendering the "old" part obsolete
2. To add information

Highlighting which part of the post was added in an edit seems to serve one purpose, which is to help people who have already read the post quickly find what has changed.

But isn't the idea of Stack Exchange posts that they answer questions for everyone who might find them in the future? Why should they care about which part has been added as an edit? Shouldn't we strive to change our post to incorporate the new information in a natural way and deleting obsolete parts of the post?

I found myself removing these blocks often with edits since I don't see a reason how they could be useful. But they are so frequent that I started questioning myself as to whether I am right by doing so.

So my question is: Is there ever a situation in which it is **better** (not just OK) to simply append new information in an "**Edit**" block?

Comment: Anecdotally, I suspect not - every time I've edited a question subsequent to a request for clarification, I do it with an "ETA: " note, but someone invariable re-edits to remove that note, and integrate the information into the body of the query.